# File Writer Android

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to write an `onPostExecute` process to file from my  **FileWriter.class**, it was working fine but am updating my application and I have to use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();` instead of this, i tried following. I know doing something slightly wrong.  Any Help or direction would be helpful.

Thanks.

```
public class FileWriter {
public void appendData( String text) {

    try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/latencyOP.csv");

        // myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        if (myFile.createNewFile()) {

            myOutWriter.append("TimeStamp,ExecutionTime,OperationType;");
        }

        myOutWriter.append(text);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        /**
         * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
         *  "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        /**
         *    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
         *                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         */
    }

 }

}
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to add that I am attempting to do some background operations and publish results on the `**FILE.csv**` thread without having to manipulate threads.

**UPDATED CODE** @Leonardo Acevedo

```
    try {
        File myFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "latencyOP.csv"
        );

        boolean needToCreateFile = !myFile.exists();
        if (needToCreateFile) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        // At this point your file is guaranteed to exist
        if (needToCreateFile) {
            myOutWriter.append("TimeStamp,ExecutionTime,OperationType;");
        }

        myOutWriter.append(text);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
       //Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void displayExceptionMessage(String msg) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Some Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**ASYNCH TASK PROCESS**

```
protected void onPreExecute(){ startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();

        long timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter();
        String data = endTime + "," + timeDiff + "," + "Authentication" + ";";
        fileWriter.appendData(data);
}
```

Is this wrong ?

```
03-14 20:42:52.062 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at com.demo.common.recordwritertest.utils.FileWriter.appendData(FileWriter.java:25)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at com.demo.common.recordwritertest.com.demo.common.recordwritertest.asynctasks.AuthenticationAsyncTask.onPostExecute(AuthenticationAsyncTask.java:119)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at com.demo.common.recordwritertest.com.demo.common.recordwritertest.asynctasks.AuthenticationAsyncTask.onPostExecute(AuthenticationAsyncTask.java:27)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
03-14 20:42:52.063 17192-17192/com.demo.common.recordwritertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Well what is wrong with your code? And why did you comment that Toast in that catch block? Use it! And tell us if you see it. Also use that other toast.

Comment: `I have to use the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()...` Well you are not doing that. Are you?

Comment: `if (myFile.createNewFile())` . Remove that. Only that. Nothing else. Leave the following block.

Comment: Please fix the grammer mistakes since it is kind of hard to understand the question. I posted an answer that i suspect answered you.